# Calculating Federal Income Tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I started a new job and am trying to understand my paycheck. I understand the state, medicare, and social security deductions, but am confused about the federal deductions. Below is what my bi-weekly paycheck states.

```
Total Earnings - 3,846.40 
Fed Taxable Gross - 3,846.40 
OASDI Gross - ...
MEDI Gross - ... 

Federal Withholding - 785.73 
Fed MED/EE - ...
Fed OASDI/EE - ...
State - ...
```

Shouldn't my federal be the following?

```
18481.25 + (0.28*((3,846.40*26)-90750)) = 21073.042 ==> /26 ==> 810.50
```

What are the possibilities for why they are not taking the full amount?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [IRS PUB 15 Employers Tax Guide For use in 2015 pages 44&45](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf)

Assuming Single and zero withholding allowances

- Fed Taxable Gross: 3846.40
- value of one withholding allowance: $153.80 x 0
- sub total: 3846.40

  ```
  Over— But not over—                      of excess over—
  $3,579 —$7,369..       $710.90 plus 28%    —$3,579
  ```

so:

```
    710.90
    +74.87 = (3846.40 - 3579) * 0.28
    equals 785.77
```

Only off by a few pennies.

Since almost everybody takes the standard deduction (or itemizes to get an even bigger deduction) and takes a personal exemption those are built into the tax tables used by your employer. That is why it gets more complex to get the withholding right  if a person has two jobs or one spouse makes a lot more than the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I wish there was an easy way to make it exact. Oh well.